# How do I select a dropdown value and display other value on the label in Powerapp?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I would like to select a dropdown value and then show some other values extracted from the excel datatable on a label. 
For instance, if I select "Jonathan Soh" in the dropdown list, the text label will show "a". Else if I select "Peter" in the dropdown list, the text label will show "b" and etc.

Below is the canvas-app formula I have tried but it can only select the dropdown list value and show dropdown list value on the text label. Please see the image for better understanding.

[image]

```
If(
    InspectorDropdown.Selected.Value = "Jonathan Soh",
    "Jonathan Soh",
    InspectorDropdown.Selected.'name ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right track with the [If function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if); in your case, you can use an expression like this one for the label:

```
If(
    InspectorDropdown.Selected.Value = "Jonathan Soh",
    "a",
    InspectorDropdown.Selected.Value = "Peter",
    "b",
    InspectorDropdown.Selected.'name ') // this last value will be used if nothing matched before
```

In this specific case, if you're always comparing with the same value, you can also use the [Switch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if), which will make the expression a little easier to read:

```
Switch(
    InspectorDropdown.Selected.Value,
    "Jonathan Son", "a",
    "Peter", "b",
    "James", "c",
    InspectorDropdown.Selected.'name ') // this last value will be used if nothing matched before
```